# Spring Batch Best Architecture to Read XML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-batch

**What is the Best performance architecture to read XML in Spring Batch? Each XML is approximately 300 KB size and we are processing 1 Million.**

### Our Current Approach

1. 30 partitions and 30 Grids and Each slave gets 166 XMLS
2. Commit Chunk 100
3. Application Start Memory is 8 GB
4. Using JAXB in Reader Default Bean Scope

```
@StepScope
@Qualifier("xmlItemReader")
public IteratorItemReader<BaseDTO> xmlItemReader(
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") List<String> fileNameList) throws Exception {
    String readingFile = "File Not Found";
    logger.info("----StaxEventItemReader----fileName--->" + fileNameList.toString());
    List<BaseDTO> fileList = new ArrayList<BaseDTO>();
    for (String filePath : fileNameList) {
        try {
            readingFile = filePath.trim();
            Invoice bill = (Invoice) getUnMarshaller().unmarshal(new File(filePath));
            UnifiedInvoiceDTO unifiedDTO = new UnifiedInvoiceDTO(bill, environment);
            unifiedDTO.setFileName(filePath);
            BaseDTO baseDTO = new BaseDTO();
            baseDTO.setUnifiedDTO(unifiedDTO);
            fileList.add(baseDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UnifiedInvoiceDTO unifiedDTO = new UnifiedInvoiceDTO();
            unifiedDTO.setFileName(readingFile);
            unifiedDTO.setErrorMessage(e);
            BaseDTO baseDTO = new BaseDTO();
            baseDTO.setUnifiedDTO(unifiedDTO);
            fileList.add(baseDTO);
        }
    }
    return new IteratorItemReader<>(fileList);
}
```

### Our questions:

1. Is this Archirecture correct
2. Is any performance or architecture advantage of using StaxEventItemReader and XStreamMarshaller over JAXB.
3. How to handle memory properly to avoid slow down

Comment: Have you considered creating a job per file? That's the best option IMO in terms of restartability, performance, scalability and all the good reasons of making one thing do one thing and do it well.

Comment: We are receiving XML filepath in a *.txt file. Each txt file have average of 5000 to max 10000 XML file path. Each txt file is creating a Job and 30 Slaves. </br> SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=13492; -- Per txt file
SELECT count(STEP_EXECUTION_ID ) FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=13492 AND STEP_NAME NOT IN('masterStep','moveFiles'); -- 31 slaves

Comment: Could you advise, Are you saying about creating a Job per *.txt file(Multiple XML file path in 1 txt file)  and each slave partition will handle 1 XML. In this case BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION have large number of records as we have 5 million XMLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a job per xml file by using the file name as a job parameter. This approach has many benefits:

- Restartability: If a job fails, you only restart the failed file (from where it left off)
- Scalability: This approach allows you to run multiple jobs in parallel. If a single machine is not enough, you can distribute the load on multiple machines
- Logging: Logs are separate by design, you don't need to use an MDC or any other technique to separate logs

> We are receiving XML filepath in a *.txt file

You can a create a script that iterates over these lines and launch a job per line (aka per file). [Gnu Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (or a similar tool) is a good option to launch jobs in parallel.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud. I will verify the performance and confirm back. We have only 1 server but very powerful with 96 CPU and 350GB RAM. We have almost 5 million XMLs and this approach creates 5 million records in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION. We need to check above increase in count have impact on Database IO.

Comment: That's not a server, that's a beast :-) Try to do a pre-analysis of the resources needed for each job on average (depending on input file size, item size, chunk size, etc) and set the JVM memory parameters accordingly. With that, your server should handle all workloads without any issue.

Comment: Mahmoud I completed the development and changed the performance drastically by your solution. Now processing one by one invoices from file with local partitions. Our performance has been changed to 1.5 million per hour inserting to multiple tables. Thanks again for the real support.